# How to make animation spread from the center?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have created animations of such obliquely moving polka dots.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#85c79f 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#fc536c 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#e99377 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#ebe49a 7px, transparent 7px);
  animation: animation1 5s infinite linear;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0, 50px 0, 25px 50px, 75px 50px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -100px -100px, -50px -100px, -75px -50px, -25px -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I would like to change this to an animation where each polka dot moves out from the center of the screen.

However, since the `background-image` property is not Animatable, I do not know how to implement it.

How can I realize this?

Comment: can you be more precise on how exactly you want the animation?

Comment: @TemaniAfif With `transform: scale`, the polka dots move from the center to the outside ([CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbRLrX)). I would like to implement this polka dots movement, but I do not want to enlarge or shrink by `transform: scale`.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the `background-size` and/or the `background-position` to obtain the needed effect:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#85c79f 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#fc536c 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#e99377 7px, transparent 7px), radial-gradient(#ebe49a 7px, transparent 7px);
  animation: animation1 5s infinite linear;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 50% calc(50% + 20px), calc(50% - 20px) 50%, calc(50% + 20px) 50%, 50% calc(50% - 20px);
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from {
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-position: calc(50% - 10px) calc(50% + 20px), calc(50% - 20px) calc(50% + 10px), calc(50% + 20px) calc(50% - 10px), calc(50% + 10px) calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  to {
    background-size: 300px 300px;
    background-position: calc(50% - 10px) calc(50% + 100px), calc(50% - 100px) calc(50% + 10px), calc(50% + 100px) calc(50% - 10px), calc(50% + 10px) calc(50% - 100px);
  }
}
```